# Lenovo webcam doesn't work with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, webcam, camera

1. Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad SL300 with integrated Syntek camera (17ef:480a)
2. OS: Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, 4.8.0-45-generic 64 bit

**Camera works in Windows 10 and** according to archive posts **it worked before with Linux**, e.g. with Ubuntu 8.10.

Xubuntu detects my camera as USB2.0 UVC PC Camera. I tried Skype, Cheese and guvcview (results below) with the same effect: **the camera LED switches ON but webcam window is black**. Starting apps with *LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so [app]* doesn't change anything.

```
tom@ThinkPad-SL300:~$ guvcview -d /dev/video0
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.2
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
...
V4L2_CORE: Control 0x80000000 failed to query with error -1
buggy V4L2_CTRL_FLAG_NEXT_CTRL flag implementation (workaround enabled)
V4L2_CORE: (get control values) empty control list
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
...
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
...
V4L2_CORE: (VIDIOC_S_PARM) error: Input/output error
V4L2_CORE: Unable to set 1/24 fps
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Is this a bug or a "feature"?